# Is there a function that returns the position of the first and last non-whitespace characters in a line?

Tags: elisp, indentation

I have a sentence. For example:

```
foo bar
```

When I do gl in Evil normal modus, that sentence turns into:

```
;; EDH: foo bar
;; ------------
```

So I need to bind the keys `gl` to a function, that will turn the sentence into the above.

Eventually I came up with:

```el
(evil-define-operator my-comment (beg end)
  "Comment selected lines."
  :motion evil-line  ;; in normal mode, no motion is read but the current line is used
  :type line         ;; this operator always works on whole lines
  (goto-char beg)
  (insert "EDH: ")
  (goto-char (+ 4 end))
  (let ((n (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position))))
    (newline)
    (insert-char ?- n)
    (comment-region beg (point))))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gl" #'my-comment)
```

This allows, e.g., to visually select some lines and then gl comments those lines and adds EDH: before the first.

Later I noticed another bug with this function. For example, I have the code formatted as following.

```
start
    foo []
```

[] = cursor. 
So I toggle `my-comment` on `foo`

Then it will be:

```
start
;; EDH:    foo
------------
```

Which is wrong, I need to make it like:

```
start
     ;; EDH: foo
     ------------
```

The culprit is the  `(line-end-position) and (line-beginning-position)`, with no respect for the indentation.
So I'm wondering if is there a Evil alternative or a built-in Emacs command, that returns the position of the `(evil-first-non-blank)` and `(evil-end-of-line)`, as well the postion of the first character in the line and the last characther in the line?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The function `current-indentation` will return the column number of the first non whitespace character on the current line.

> (current-indentation)
>
> Return the indentation of the current line. This is the horizontal
>   position of the character following any initial whitespace.

If you want the character position of the first non whitespace character on the line you could use `(save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (point))`

> (backward-to-indentation &optional ARG)
>
> Move backward ARG lines and position at first nonblank character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replaced the `(- (line-end [..] beginning postion)` with your `(save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (point)` but it didn't helped in my case. I assume I placed it on the wrong place?

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh: this post provides an answer to the question you stated (non-whitespace bounds on a line).  If you have a different question, either edit your post or ask a new question that states precisely what the problem is.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is the position of the last non-whitespace character of the line:`(save-excursion
                                        (end-of-line)
                                        (skip-syntax-backward "-")
                                        (point))`

Answer (score 2):

The following function returns a list of the point positions of the first and last non-whitespace characters on the current line:

```el
(defun line-bounds-nonwhitespace ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-at-bol))
    (skip-syntax-forward " " (point-at-eol))
    (let ((beg (point)))
      (goto-char (point-at-eol))
      (skip-syntax-backward " " (point-at-bol))
      (list beg (point)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replaced the `(- (line-end [..] beginning postion)` with your `(line-bounds-non-whitespace)` but it didn't helped in my case. I assume I placed it on the wrong place? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh: this post provides an answer to the question you stated (non-whitespace bounds on a line).  If you have a different question, either edit your post or ask a new question that states precisely what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already understand that. But I couldn't figure out how I could integrate your post into the code that I posted in the OP. Hence my question.